# To use OR( || ) or to create different functions?

Tags: require

The question is, should i use a require statement with logical OR,.... or should i create a new function for each condition?

How much in gas does it cost to check 6x logical or conditions?

```
function doSomething() external {
 require(msg.sender == address1 || msg.sender == address2 || msg.sender == address3 || msg.sender == address4 || msg.sender == address5 || msg.sender == address6);
//whatever here
}



function doSomething1() external {
 require(msg.sender == address1);
//whatever
}
function doSomething2() external {
 require(msg.sender == address2);
//whatever
}
```

..and so on for all the other addresses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each condition check cost reading a storage variable, which is between 2100 and 100 depending on how cold or warm the information is. I would suggest if you will have several storage variables with the same type use a mapping if what you are doing will always be the same because having more functions means more deployment cost, like this:

```
mapping(address => bool) public acceptedAddresses;

function doSomething() external {
 require(acceptedAddresses[msg.sender]);
//whatever here
}
```

Reference for gas cost the G appendix of the [Yellow Paper](https://ethereum.github.io/yellowpaper/paper.pdf)

Comment: Thanks.
And what's the difference between reading a variable and an array?
`require(acceptedAddresses[msg.sender]);`
vs
`require(msg.sender == trustedAddress);`

Is the (gas)difference negligible or is it something worth keeping in mind?

Wondering to use different functions with require custom msg sender, or to use your solution.

The deployment cost is not a problem as it will be launched on another EVM-compatitible network with cheaper fees.

Comment: To clarify, I suggested using a `mapping` not an array, they are built different internally and arrays does cost more than mappings. in your case since you'll need to save several of the same type and not just one, a mapping will prevent 5 calls to read storage and will be more cost efficient for you.

Comment: Ah yes, mapping not array is what i meant. 

The question now is to make 5 separate functions(first one requires msg.sender == acceptedAddress1, second one requires acceptedAddress2,...) and i would call correct function name from those contracts

OR
just create one function that checks 
`require(acceptedAddresses[msg.sender])`

I assume the first would cost more to deploy, but what are the gas savings for the user? Is there significant difference between
`require(msg.sender == acceptedAddress1)`
and
`require(acceptedAddresses[msg.sender])`